# Comparison of Reactive programming and Complex Event processing

Tags: reactive-programming, complex-event-processing

I have been reading up on the reactive programming and can understand the programming model and how we can use patterns such as CQRS to build micro services & applications. How is this different from the legacy Complex event processing approach used by traditional middleware.

Comment: @beaker This is not a good fit for Software Engineering, at least in its current state. It's far too broad - we expect questions to focus on a specific problem and have evidence of research being done.

Comment: @beaker In the future, please refrain from suggesting other sites to people. This question was cross-posted on Software Engineering, where it was promptly down voted and closed. That leads to a poor user experience.

Comment: @ThomasOwens You got it, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

One can compare apples and oranges yes. And using the word "legacy" for oranges is probably not appropriate. The reactive programming is about general-purpose programming APIs for dataflows, push, pull, threading, backpressure etc.. Such as provided by an actor library. CEP is about analyzing events and provides a language (SQL, rules, XML) to make it easy and concise to detect situations in an event stream. CEP is provided by a CEP engine. For example to find a train-passing event without a train-station-stop event within 10 seconds you can express this situation detection in a CEP engine using just 60 characters. If you write programming language code to detect such a situation in say Java it probably upwards of 20 lines of code and is much harder to read. The CEP engine will do more for you such as being very fast in matching events with which rules they apply to. This for the case when you have many situations to detect. CEP engines and reactive programming can well be used together and are in fully in synergy and do not provide at all the same functionality.